# ftp batch file invalid login

Tags: ftp, batch-file

I am trying to create a simple ftp batch file to upload a handful of files on a regular basis but I cannot seem to get the login right.  I can take the same credentials and log in through Filezilla without issue but from the command line it's not working.

Here is what I am attempting:

```
ECHO Creating Script File for FTP Download for District %2....
ECHO open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx >ftp.scr
ECHO myuser >>ftp.scr
ECHO mypassword >>ftp.scr
ECHO bin >>ftp.scr
ECHO send %1 >>ftp.scr
ECHO quit >>ftp.scr

ftp -s:ftp.scr
```

Simple and to the point I believe.

Here is what it is responding with:

```
D:\Suburban>ftp -s:ftp.scr
ftp> open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 5 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 10:16. Server port: 21.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
User (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:(none)):
331 User myuser  OK. Password required

530 Login authentication failed
Login failed.
ftp> bin
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
ftp> send webtrn25.001
530 You aren't logged in
530 You aren't logged in
ftp> quit
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
```

I thought this should be straight forward, but seems nothing ever is... This has to be something simple I'm overlooking.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

** EDIT **

Let me also add, if I run these commands straight up from the command line, I am able to log in via ftp:

```
D:\Suburban>ftp
ftp> open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 5 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 10:19. Server port: 21.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
User (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:(none)): myuser
331 User myuser OK. Password required
Password:
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
ftp>
```

Answer (score 2):

I debated deleting this, the mods might still do so, but I figured out my issue. figured it might help someone later down the road...

```
ECHO myuser >>ftp.scr
ECHO mypassword >>ftp.scr
```

The space between the name/password and the >> was the issue.

Once I changed it to:

```
ECHO myuser>>ftp.scr
ECHO mypassword>>ftp.scr
```

It worked fine!